# Select something with location unkown from all tables in database in mysql

Tags: mysql, select, grep

I have a varchar with the value of say `Foo` somewhere in my database and I don't know where exactly.

Is it possible to create a query that will search all tables and all columns for this content? Similar to `grep`

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an easy way to do this, but you could use the information schema to find all your varchar columns.

```
SELECT table_name, column_name 
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE data_type = 'varchar';
```

You could then write a query to produce a list of queries that you would need to run to search for your term.

```
SELECT CONCAT(
    'select ', column_name, 
    ' from ', table_name, 
    ' where ', column_name, ' like \'%foo%\''
) AS stmt
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE data_type = 'varchar';
```

A more advanced example might insert matches into a results table along with the table and column names.

Answer (score 0):

There is a stored procedure here (http://forge.mysql.com/tools/tool.php?id=232) for MySQL which will create a table for storing output, then loop through information_schema database's COLUMNS table to obtain all database's table and column names. Next execute a count(*) query on database.table for each column with appropriate search string in where condition. If count(*) > 0, that perticular column has the search term, so it will insert that triplet (database name, table name, column name) into a table. Last Select * from table to view respective database table and column names having the search term.

Answer (score 0):

I found a very very simple way of doing it.

`mysqldump -u user -p mydatabase | grep foo`